# How to prevent Android Emulator from disconnecting proxied Wifi

Tags: android, fiddler

I often have to debug https traffic for the Android apps I am developing. I use Fiddler for that, running on my Windows host machine, setup as a proxy (10.0.2.2 / 8888) in the Wifi settings of the Android emulator. Fiddly, but it works fine.

However, after a bit of inactivity (i.e. typing code, looking at Fiddler logs, effectively all the time) the Android emulator concludes that it can no longer reach the internet because of this proxy.

[image]

I then have to go through the process of

1. Remove proxy
2. Reconnect wifi
3. Enter proxy settings again

This is kinda of killing my flow, so is there any way to stop this from happening? Is it pinging a domain I can somehow whitelist?

Comment: Since about v9 Android has a built-in feature to "rate" WiFi and other network connections. By default it tries to use the connection with the highest rating, and it looks like your proxy has a lower rating. No regular devices you can disable this whole rating stuff in Wifi/network settings. Not sure about the emulator. Just check the advanced network settings. BTW: Have you rooted the emulator and installed Fiddler's root CA cert as system certificate?

Comment: I'll check out the rating behavior, thanks! I wouldn't expect the wifi to switch to "not connected" then, but it sounds promising. I have indeed installed the Fiddler root cert, the app I am monitoring does not allow untrusted SSL. I have not rooted the emulator, are there practical benefits from doing so?